# 107/5000 Which widget is better in Flutter to perform curves that serve as background: CustomShape or CustomPaint?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am learning to develop UI, so using curves as part of the background I found these 2 tools and I cannot fully understand when it is better to use one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reference this doc https://medium.com/@felixblaschke/fancy-background-animations-in-flutter-4163d50f5c37 
github https://github.com/felixblaschke/simple_animations_example_app

code snippet from https://github.com/felixblaschke/simple_animations_example_app/blob/master/lib/examples/fancy_background.dart

```
class CurvePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double value;

  CurvePainter(this.value);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final white = Paint()..color = Colors.white.withAlpha(60);
    final path = Path();

    final y1 = sin(value);
    final y2 = sin(value + pi / 2);
    final y3 = sin(value + pi);

    final startPointY = size.height * (0.5 + 0.4 * y1);
    final controlPointY = size.height * (0.5 + 0.4 * y2);
    final endPointY = size.height * (0.5 + 0.4 * y3);

    path.moveTo(size.width * 0, startPointY);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 0.5, controlPointY, size.width, endPointY);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, white);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[image]